# how do I only allow one selected button at a time? / make button know if i click somewhere else

Tags: iphone, objective-c, select, uibutton

how do i make these buttons so that only one can be used at a time? Im not getting any errors right now when i run btw. Im just looking for a solution to my challenge. Thanks for any help

they are generated in a for loop like this:

```
    for (int l=0; l<list.length; l++) {  

        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton setTag:l];
        CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(11+charact*20, -40 + line*50, 18, 21);
        aButton.frame = buttonRect;

        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [aButton setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [gameScroll addSubview:aButton];
}
```

And then the action for when a button is clicked is:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    int tag = sender.tag;

    if (sender.selected == TRUE) {
        [sender setSelected:FALSE];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    else if (sender.selected == FALSE) {
        [sender setSelected:TRUE];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
}
```

right now everything works but i want it to know if theres already a button selected and deselect that other button, or else to **automatically deselect any time the user clicks outside of the range of that button**

thanks in advance

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by putting the sender tags in a Dictionary. Here's the link to what i ended up doing. Thanks for the help everyone. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6241193/creating-a-mutable-array-that-can-be-added-to-in-later-clicks-of-the-same-button)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest to put all ur buttons to Array in your button initialisation

```
NSMutableArray* buttons = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity: list.length];

for (int l=0; l<list.length; l++) {  

        UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [aButton setTag:l];
        CGRect buttonRect = CGRectMake(11+charact*20, -40 + line*50, 18, 21);
        aButton.frame = buttonRect;

        [aButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [aButton setTitle:@" " forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [gameScroll addSubview:aButton];
        [buttons addObject: aButton];
}
```

and every time buttonClicked triggered, then do your logic:

```
for (UIButton* button in buttons)
    {
        if (button != sender)
        {
             [button setSelected: FALSE];
             [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        }
    }

int tag = sender.tag;

    if (sender.selected == TRUE) {
        [sender setSelected:FALSE];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
    else if (sender.selected == FALSE) {
        [sender setSelected:TRUE];
        [sender setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }
```

hope helps :)

Comment: hey thanks. Ive put them in an array but it hasnt seemed to solve the problem. When I click a second button the first one remains selected. Any idea why that is? Thanks again for the help!

Comment: hi, there is typo in my code... it suppose to be button not sender... for the buttonClicked triggered, I edited the answer.

Comment: this still doesnt seem to work for some reason. I changed the setBackgroundcolor in your for loop to make it clearColor instead of red (i want to indicate that the button has been deselected) but it still leaves all buttons selected..

Comment: wow, some weirdness going on there... maybe if u put into pastebin, I could help more

:)

Comment: well i got it working. not sure what the issue was now but i think i was forgetting to declare the properties on my array or something. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can store currently selected button in a separate variable and deselect it in buttonClicked: method:

```
- (void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

    int tag = sender.tag;

    currentButton.selected = NO;
    if (currentButton != sender){
       currentButton = sender;
       currentButton.selected = YES;
    }
    else{
       currentButton = nil;
    }
}
```

Also you can specify background colour for each state in button itself so you actually don't need to change it each time manually

If you also want to deselect your button when user just touches the screen you can implement  touchesEnded:withEvent: in your view controller and reset currentButton in it (that method will get called if no other control intercept the touch event - so it may not be sufficient in all cases)

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
    currentButton.selected = NO;
    currentButton = nil;
}
```

Comment: Hi so for this to work I'm assuming i need to first create some sort of object "currentButton"? Is that right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yes, you will need separate instance variable for that

Comment: how do i create that variable so that i can recall it in the next click? it seems to get wiped out and start fresh every time a button is pressed

Comment: It must be declared as an instance variable in your current class(not a local variable in method if that's the case)

Comment: right yes thanks. i did integrate this solution into my code. Thanks for the help :)