# creating a Mutable array that can be added to in later clicks of the same button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ipad, nsmutablearray

General noob questions:

(1) How can I create an `NSMutable` array in a `buttonClicked` action that I can add more entries to during subsequent clicks of the same button? I always seem to start over with a new array at every click (the array prints with only 1 entry which is the most recent button's tag in an `NSLog` statement).

I have about 100 buttons (one for each character in my string called "list") generated by a for-loop earlier in my code, and each has been assigned a tag. They are in a scrollview within the view of my `ViewController`.

**I wish to keep track of how many (and which ones) of the buttons have been clicked** with the option of **removing those entries if they are clicked a second time**.

This is what I have so far:

```
-(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender
      NSMutableArray * theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: list.length];
      NSNumber *sendNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
      [theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked addObject:sendNum at index:sender.tag];
      NSLog(@"%@",theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked);
}
```

(2) I have read that I may be able to use a plist dictionary but I don't really understand how I would accomplish that in code since I cant type out the items in the dictionary manually (since I don't know which buttons the user will click). Would this be easier if I somehow loaded and replaced the dictionary in a plist file? And how would I do that?

(3) I also have no idea how I should memory manage this since I need to keep updating the array. `autorelease`?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: You should try to tag better the question. You will improve the possibility of having it answer. You should remove the button tag and replace it by some technology/API name (iphone, whatever, I don't know). I already tagged it as "apple", and objective-c. Please notice that there are people who subscribe these big names as rss feeds.

Comment: awesome thanks for the advice! I was wondering why there were 4 views lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, firstly you are creating a locally scoped array that is being re-initialised on every call to **buttonClicked:**. The variable should be part of the class init cycle.

You will also be better off with an **NSMutableDictionary** instead of an NSMutableArray. With a dictionary we don't have to specify capacity and we can use the button's tags as dictionary keys.

Here's what you need to do, these three steps always go together: **property/synthesize/release**. A good one to remember.

```
  //Add property declaration to .h file
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableDictionary * theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked;

  //Add the synthesize directive to the top of .m file
  @synthesize theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked;

  // Add release call to the dealloc method at the bottom of .m file
  - (void) dealloc {
    self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked = nil; // syntactically equiv to [theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked release] but also nulls the pointer
    [super dealloc];
  }
```

Next we create a storage object when the class instance is initialised. Add this to your class's **init** or **viewDidLoad** method.

```
 self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] dictionary]; // convenience method for creating a dictionary
```

And your updated **buttonClicked:** method should look more like this.

```
    -(void) buttonClicked:(UIButton *)sender {

         NSNumber *senderTagAsNum = [NSNumber numberWithInt:sender.tag];
         NSString *senderTagAsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",senderTagAsNum];

         // this block adds to dict on first click, removes if already in dict
         if(![self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked objectForKey:senderTagAsString]) {
           [self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked setValue:senderTagAsNum forKey:senderTagAsString];
         } else {
           [self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked removeObjectForKey:senderTagAsString];                }
         [senderTagAsString release];
         NSLog(@"%@", self.theseButtonsHaveBeenClicked);
}
```

Comment: this is spectacular. Thanks so much for the help. I hit a road block and have been stuck all weekend! you rock

Comment: should the property declaration  of the Dictionary have retain instead of readonly? it comes up with an error in the dealloc. And when I change that, I get a SIGABRT saying that 'dictionary' in the viewdidload is an unrecognized selector

Comment: ok i managed to fix it by converting the NSNumber to a string and using that as the key. i fixed the answer above to include this.

Comment: @aking63: Yes, it should be retain not readonly. I guess my hands just got carried away on that one! No Xcode code sense when typing into Chrome :D Hope that didn't throw you.

Comment: well i got it figured out. Thanks so much. huge help.